# Find resistance r1 and r2 using vin and vout

Tags: voltage, resistors, circuit-design, voltage-divider, series

I have tried everything.I have tried all voltage divider rule but i need atleast r1 or r2. Can anyone help me understand to solve it?
No need of solution just set me on right path.

[image: Please dont tell me solution.Just tell me How to solve it]

Comment: You can't definitively get values for R1 and R2 only a ratio of values.

Comment: Here is question statement. What could be the values of R1 and R2 in the circuit shown below such that the output voltage Vo across
R2 is 9V? I have spent hours. Its a very imp assignment question.If you will help me i will be grateful.

Comment: With the information provided, you can only determine the required ratio between the resistor values, not the absolute values of either resistor.

Comment: Ok.  It is an assignment.  The point of it is for you to learn the very thing that Andy has pointed out.  Basically, any two resistors that provides the desired output will be correct.  Now a leading question:  How many value pairs do you think exist that can provide the desired output voltage from the given input voltage?

Comment: If the problem statement is "what *could* be the values", then pick an arbitrary value for R1 and solve for R2.

Comment: Alot of pairs can exist.If i suppose values of r1 and r2 than the vout should be 9. How do i find resistance value which will do it for me without using internet voltage divider calculators

Comment: Can anyone confirm me my answer if its a correct method?

Comment: Pick one of the resistors as 1k or 10k. They're nice common 'middling' values that, if you have no other way to set the absolute values, will do for measurement purposes. That is light load on battery, and low enough resistance to drive a DMM with little error. Of course, if you need to drive a load, or have some other information, then you would have a reason for choosing other values. In all cases, R2 = 3* R1, so no need for internet calculators. Unless the output is loaded, in which case it's R2//Rload = 3 * R1.

Comment: R1 is 25% greater than R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried everything.I have tried all voltage divider rule but i need atleast r1 or r2.

That is correct. You have two unknowns and one equation.

Here are some resistances they can be

- R1 = 3 Ω, R2 = 9 Ω
- R1 = 30 Ω, R2 = 90 Ω
- R1 = 300 Ω, R2 = 900 Ω
- R1 = 3000 Ω, R2 = 9000 Ω

And it's impossible for you to identify which it is.

So no, you can't identify their values from the 12 V and 9 V alone.

---

You can however lock some value, important parameters that you want to lock might be:

- The power dissipated by R1 and R2
- The current through R1 and R2
- The resistance of R1 or R2

So let's say you want the current to be 1 A, then R1 is 3 Ω and R2 is 9 Ω.

Or let's say you want to dissipate 100 mW, then R1 is 360 Ω and R2 is 1080 Ω.

Or let's say you know R1 = 100 Ω, then R2 is 300 Ω.

Comment: @Nouman: if it helped you (and I hope it did, because it is correct), please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
Rout is 9.So I can assume its Vin (subtract sign)3.
Now put this in voltage divider formula. 
Answer will be R1=-1.333R2 .
It means the R2 value will always be 1.333 less than r2. 
i tested it one random values and they all are giving me answer 9.xxxx.

Comment: According to your assumption, R1 is negative. How is R1 negative? How can you have a negative resistance?

Comment: yes you are right. What do u suggest?

Comment: **I suggest you understand Harry's answer that you've already thanked him for.** :) What he says is correct afterall.

Comment: i tried it different way.I did vin=vout+3. It gave me positive resistance.But when i found vout using that resistance it gave me 10.xxx  on every resistance value but its better than nothing. I am gonna add harry solution but i also want to add if it can be done in any way possible. What do u think?

Comment: @Nouman The problem is that you have nothing that relates to the current. - Ohm's law states => V = I×R, You know V but you don't know I or R. It's unsolvable only knowing V.